# When dealloc is called in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If i create a simple class like this

```
@interface table : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray *array;
}

@end
```

and in the Init method I call: `array = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] init];`
and in the dealloc method I call: `[array release];`

but I have a memory leek because the dealloc method is never called. I must call the dealloc method by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object's retain count hits 0 it is marked by the run time for cleanup. When the run time cleans up the object and reclaims the memory, dealloc is called giving it a chance to clean any other object references to instance variables or the like. Does that help? If you want to see it called, put

```
NSLog(@"%s", _cmd);
```

or a break point at the beginning of your dealloc method and watch the debugger/console.

Comment: the program don't go in the dealloc method if I put a breakPoint. My class is a singleton, it can changed something?

Comment: A singleton by definition will not be deallocated, so the dealloc method will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should never directly call `[self dealloc]`. What is it that gives you the impression that `-dealloc` is never called?

**EDIT**: You should never need to call `[table dealloc]` either. The only time you should ever send a `dealloc` message is when overriding `dealloc` and calling `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: Because I run with the leek tools, and he said that this table leek, and I put a breakpoint in the dealloc method and it's never called...

Comment: So then the main question is "when do you call [myTable release]?"

Answer (score 0):

This all looks correct.  Your instance of class `table` here, will have it's `dealloc` method called when it is completely released.  So you only have a leak if the way you use your class causes the entire instance of `table` to leak.

But, of course, the same rules apply for any classes that uses your `table` class.